# Return Largest Number in Array using spread syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, spread-syntax

I'm trying to find the largest number in each sub array using this function:

```
/* jshint esversion: 6 */
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var max=[];
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++){

     max.push(Math.max(...arr[j]));
    }

  }
  return max;

}

largestOfFour([[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

but when I run it, the result is, in fact, the largest numbers in each subarray, but repeated 4 times, like this:

```
[27,5,39,1001,27,5,39,1001,27,5,39,1001,27,5,39,1001]
```

and I'm not sure why. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong, thanks.

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to return the array that has the single highest number in it?

Comment: you are finding the highest number in the array. the other array is an array of arrays. note that `Math.max()` as shown consumes an array, so there's no need to sub-loop, and in fact, by doing so, you're pushing the same data _arr.length_ times

Comment: Remove the second loop.

Comment: Why not just sort each array and then get the number at the `length-1` index?

Comment: @Aron Sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm trying to find the largest number in each sub array.

Comment: Another short version is: `largestOf = arr => arr.map(x => Math.max(...x));`

Comment: Your code doesn't even work with a non-quadratic matrix, i.e. when the inner and outer arrays have different lengths.

Comment: Thank you @dandavis for your explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the second loop:

```js
    /* jshint esversion: 6 */
    function largestOfFour(arr) {
      var max=[];
      for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
         max.push(Math.max(...arr[i]));
      }
      return max;
    }
    
    console.log(largestOfFour([[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array#map` the array into the max of each sub array:

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map((sub) => Math.max(...sub));
}

console.log(largestOfFour([[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also do recursively as follows in a Haskellesque pattern matching fashion;

```js
function getLargests([x,...xs]){
  return [Math.max(...x)].concat(xs.length ? getLargests(xs) : []);
}

var arr = [[13, 27, 18, 26], [4, 5, 1, 3], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];
console.log(getLargests(arr));
```